# Codeigniter Escaping Data

Tags: php, security, codeigniter

I am using the following code to allow me to add data to my db but it seems the `$this->db->escape();`is not working as I can add html tags and they will run in the view :(

**Code:**

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('aPartyLocation','A Party Location', 'required|trim|prep_for_form|max_length[35]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('aPartyPhone','A Party Phone', 'required|trim|numeric|max_length[35]|xss_clean');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
            {
                $userData = array(
                    'location' => $this->input->post('aPartyLocation', TRUE),
                    'phone' => $this->input->post('aPartyPhone', TRUE));

                $this->db->escape($userData);
                $this->party_model->addAParty($userData);
```

**Update:**

**Controller:**

```
$userData = array(
    'id' => $id,
    'location' => html_escape($this->input->post('aPartyLocation', TRUE)),
    'phone' => html_escape($this->input->post('aPartyPhone', TRUE))
    );
```

**Model:**

```
function addAParty($userData = NULL)
{
    $this->db->insert('aParty',$userData);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you use [CodeIgniter's Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) class. This automatically escapes data for you.

For example, an insert statement would look like:

```
$this->db->insert('yourTable',array(
                 'location' => $this->input->post('aPartyLocation',TRUE),
                 'phone' => $this->input->post('aPartyPhone')
           ));
```

The second argument, is an array where the keys correspond to the columns in your database.

---

**Edit**

I believe Active Record only sanitizes data for SQL injection attacks. Passing the second parameter to `$this->input->post()` as TRUE protects your from XSS attacks. However, neither of those escape HTML tags. For that, you can use the [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function.

```
 $this->db->insert('yourTable',array(
                     'location' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('aPartyLocation',TRUE)),
                     'phone' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('aPartyPhone'))
                ));
```

---

```
$location = $this->input->post('aPartyLocation',TRUE);
$phone = $this->input->post('aPartyPhone');

 $this->db->insert('yourTable',array(
                     'location' => htmlspecialchars($location),
                     'phone' => htmlspecialchars($phone)
                ));
```

Comment: I have placed my model into my question,  would I just run a 3rd value?

Comment: No, the way you are doing it is correct. Are the inputs still not being escaped?

Comment: Tried ur edit and got Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW

Comment: You've probably missed a comma or something somewhere. Simply wrapping the inputs in a function should not case a parse error.

Comment: Try my new code (edited answer). It'll make debugging easier.

Comment: Thanks @xbonez Could I have ur advice on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023699/codeigniter-session-returning-310-redirect

Comment: No problem, and sure, I'll have a look.

Comment: p.s. If you set the global setting to protect agains XSS, you don't need the 2nd param `$config[‘global_xss_filtering’] = TRUE;`